# What does Alloc Limit mean in Opera TV Emulator?

Tags: memory, opera, alloc

Opera TV Emulator User Guide says it can config both alloc limit and heap limit. Heap limit is obvious. But alloc limit means what?

https://dev.opera.com/tv/opera-tv-emulator/#settings

Answer (score 0):

According to [Opera for Devices: Out of Memory System](https://dev.opera.com/tv/opera-for-devices-out-of-memory-system/), heap size means process heap size which Opera has allocated, including user interface and plugins. Allocation size means the amount of memory that Opera has allocated, which should be smaller than heap size.

Alloc limit is used to internally keeps track of the amount of memory that Opera has allocated, and force-fails any allocations that would cause the total to exceed the allowed limit.